# Encrypting specific columns in Hibernate: What to do with existing data and how to correctly implement @ColumnTransformer?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have built a web application with a MySQL database that holds patients data. According to **GDPR** patients names must be encrypted inside the database. For connecting and performing operations to db, I use Hibernate 5.

Searching the web, I have found a lot of info regarding how to encrypt a specific column or columns inside a db table. Mainly the following three approaches:

- Using `@ColumnTransformer` annotation of **Hibernate** which is the least destructive to existing code and requires the least code to be written
- Using *Jasypt* and its Hibernate integration which is more destructive to existing code and requires a few lines of code.
- Implementing a JPA Attribute Converter which required quite a few lines to be written

I decided to use `@ColumnTransformer` which seems to be the easiest implementation. If you think that one of the other approaches is better please say it and also explain the reason.

My question, however, has to do with existing data. My db already has data that is unencrypted which must be encrypted to work with `@ColumnTransformer` implementation. I intend to use the following annotation:

```
@ColumnTransformer(
    read = "pgp_sym_decrypt(lastName, 'mySecretKey')", 
    write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(?, 'mySecretKey')"
)
```

and

```
@ColumnTransformer(
    read = "pgp_sym_decrypt(firstName, 'mySecretKey')", 
    write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(?, 'mySecretKey')"
)
```

to the corresponding columns.

How should I encrypt existing data to comply with the above annotations? What SQL code should I use?

Comment: It is a bit out of the scope but hard-coding the "secret key" in a source code is a very bad idea - it is not a secret any more.

Comment: I have changed it ;-)

Comment: Well, yes, so we do not see that (I mean it is not published on stackoverflow). But anyone who has access to your source code, has access to your data. And you cannot change your key and re-encrypt your data whenever necessary without re-building the software. Basically, these are rather bad security practices and I doubt any respectful IT security team would approve it.

But again, I respect that this is potentially out of scope of the discussion, I just wanted to make sure that others reading it are aware of it, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL supports the following functions:

- AES_ENCRYPT(str, key_str);
- AES_DECRYPT(crypt_str,key_str);

However, I **can't** update all MySQL entries using the following (because aes_encrypt returns binary):

```
UPDATE Patient SET firstName=AES_ENCRYPT(firstName, "mySecretKey"), lastName=AES_ENCRYPT(lastName, "mySecretKey") //NOT WORKING
```

The solution is:

1. Rename existing columns using MySQLcommand:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Patient CHANGE firstName firstName-old;

   ALTER TABLE Patient CHANGE lastName lastName-old;
   ```
2. Create two new MySQL columns of type `varbinary(512)` with command:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Patient ADD COLUMN lastName VARBINARY(512) NOT NULL;

   ALTER TABLE Patient ADD COLUMN firstName VARBINARY(512) NOT NULL;
   ```
3. Update the new columns from the old ones with the following command:

   ```
   UPDATE `gourvas_platform`.`Patient` SET firstName=aes_encrypt(`firstName-old`, "my secret"), lastName=aes_encrypt(`lastName-old`, "mysecret");
   ```
4. Now we can safely delete the old columns
5. Finally use the following Hibernate `@ColumnTransformer` annotations:

   ```
   @ColumnTransformer(
       read = "AES_DECRYPT(lastName, 'mySecretKey')", 
       write = "AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'mySecretKey')"
   )
   ```

   and

   ```
   @ColumnTransformer(
       read = "AES_DECRYPT(firstName, 'mySecretKey')", 
       write = "AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'mySecretKey')"
   )
   ```

**Note:** If you are using MySql 8 and beyond skip this step. Because I'm using MySQL 5.7 and AES_DECRYPT function returns `binary[]` instead of `String`,  I need to `cast` to text. So the above `@ColumnTransformer` needs to be changed to the following:

```
@ColumnTransformer(
read = "cast(aes_decrypt(lastName, 'my secret') as char(255))", 
write = "aes_encrypt(?, 'mysecret')"
)
```

and

```
@ColumnTransformer(
read = "cast(aes_decrypt(firstName, 'myscret') as char(255))", 
write = "aes_encrypt(?, 'mysecret')"
)
```

Comment: To make collation work you need to cast to char even on never versions of MySQL / MariaDB